# can't serve static files spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static

I'm really new to spring and that's why it can be very stupid question, but I got troubled with serving static files. I'm creating a REST api for library app and have some logic when user tries to add a book:

1. I get principal user from SecurityContextHolder.
2. I add book and add book to user's list of books
3. I read the bytes from base64 encoded string and write it to pdf file, stored in /resources/static

And that works. But I don't know how to get this file. I tried to do next:

1. I made `ResourceConfig` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurer`, but it's not worked:

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
        .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
        .addResourceLocations(StaticAbsolutePath.getPath());
    }
}
```

2. Oh, the `StaticAbsolutePath.getPath()` is the metod I made to get path to static directory:

```java
public class StaticAbsolutePath {
    private static final String path = "A:\\java\\projects\\books\\src\\main\\resources\\static";

    public StaticAbsolutePath() {
    }
    public static String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

3. I decided that my security config is blocking this path cuz I'm not authorized, so I added this to config class:

```java
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll();
```

But it'a also was useless. When I try to serf to `http://localhost:8080/static/1252356147.pdf`, it says that "Whitelabel Error Page".

And here is the screen of resources directory:

[image]

So if you know what can be the problem, please tell me, I'd really apreciate it!

Here is the full code of SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/login/**").permitAll();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users/").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/current").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/books/**").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/books/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/books/**").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll();
        http.addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I understood that in resources/staic directory should be stored files like HTML and CSS thanks to @Akhil. And I also added the lines of code that he suggested. So my `ResourceConfig` class now looks like this:

```java
private static final String[] CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "A:\\downloads\\"
    };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
        .addResourceHandler("/pdf/**")
        .addResourceLocations(CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
        .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().cachePrivate())
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
```

And I changed the directory to store user uploaded files:

[image]

But it still not working :(

Full project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, static files mean files that rarely change for example HTML, CSS files, etc. In your case, the user can upload a pdf file anytime that indicates it's not a static file. What I would suggest is to use a different directory to store PDF and give that path in your resourceConfig. However, if you want to store it in your /resources/static directory then you can do something like this.

ResourceConfigs:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ResourceConfigs implements WebMvcConfigurer {



    private static final String[] CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "A:\\downloads\\pdfFiles\\"
    };


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pdf/**")
                .addResourceLocations(CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().cachePrivate())
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }

}
```

With this configuration, you can have links like this,
http://localhost:8080/pdf/**

You don't need to configure spring security for this

Comment: Well, ok, thanks, now I understand what kind of files should be stored in static directory. But I added the lines of code that u suggested and getting this file is still now working. I added my new ResourceConfig under **UPDATE** in my question.

Comment: Can you send me your project structure?

Comment: sure, I added it to question

Comment: No, you should not store the PDF or any files in the com.books.books package. because think what will happen when you make a JAR file of your project and run it somewhere.

For starters create a folder outside our project and store PDFs there. In production, you have to either store it in the server where you are running the JAR file or use third-party storage providers like AWS S3.

Comment: Well, ok, I see. Now I created the file in another directory, in A:\\downloads. So I just chnged the value of `CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS` th this and it's also shows me Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: can you send me the path where you are storing images?

Comment: I'm storing in`A:\downloads` and my project stored in `A:\java\projects\courier_tracker_api`

Comment: I have updated the answer you can try with the above configuration.

Comment: Well, yeah, I did the same as you wrote but it's still not working. The spring gets the handler /pdf/**, but it can't get the file from the directory. I also tried to add there a .png file, but result is the same :/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/jj710207(v=vs.85)

//Specifying a drive and a file name.

try this and let me know.

Comment: I changed the path to `file:///A|/downloads/` as was it was in the link, but result is the same.

Comment: The location provided in CLASS_PATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS is not proper.I did the same thing in ubuntu and it worked , for windows also it should unless you dont provide proper path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247372/discussion-between-akhil-and-cross).